Why can't these two types unify after an undefined check?
I have the following
export type WithRequired<T, K extends keyof T> = T & { [P in K]-?: T[P] };

type A = {
  f1?: string;
};

function test(a: A): WithRequired<A, 'f1'> {
  if (a.f1) {
    return a;
  } else {
    throw Error();
  }
}

however, this gives an error
Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'WithRequired<A, "f1">'.
  Type 'A' is not assignable to type '{ f1: string; }'.
    Types of property 'f1' are incompatible.
      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

I guess I would have expected this to work, since in the context of this branch, the compiler knows that a.f1 is not undefined....and in some contexts, typescript will do this correctly.
I guess I have two questions

why doesn't this work? (to understand the compiler better)
is there a way to make something like this work without a cast?



Narrowing properties does not narrow an entire object type, unless the object is of a discriminated union type and the property is the discriminant. (and A is not a union at all, so ) I believe ms/TS#42384 is the currently open feature request for that. 2) You could do a spread like this but if you insist on just returning a then you'll need the equivalent of a type assertion (what you're calling a "cast"). Does that fully address the question(s)? If so I'll write up a full answer. If not, what am I missing?


@jcalz yes that answers it exactly, thank you. If you write it up I'll accept it!

Unless a is of a discriminated union type and f1 is its discriminant property, then checking a.f1 will only serve to narrow a.f1 and not a itself. Since a is of type A, which is not union at all (let alone a discriminated union), then a will stubbornly stay of type A even though a.f1 is known to be string.
There is an open feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#42384 for property checks to narrow their parents as well, but for now it's not part of the language. Until and unless that is implemented, you'll need to work around it.
The easiest workaround is to use a type assertion, but you don't want to do that.  Another approach is to use object spread to make a new object out of pieces of a such that the compiler verifies the new type:
function test(a: A): WithRequired<A, 'f1'> {
  if (a.f1) {
    return { ...a, f1: a.f1 };
  } else {
    throw Error();
  }
}

Since a is seen as type A but a.f1 is seen as string, then { ...a, f1: a.f1 } will be seen as equivalent to WithRequired<A, 'f1'>, and there's now no error.
Playground link to code

'a' is not of the type you return, so you must cast it in your code. Another approach is to use type predicates:
type WithRequired<T, K extends keyof T> = T & { [P in K]-?: T[P] };

type A = {
  f1?: string;
};

function isWithRequired<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, k: K): obj is WithRequired<T,K> {
  return Boolean(obj[k]);
}

function test(a: A): WithRequired<A, 'f1'> {
  if(isWithRequired(a, 'f1')){
    return a;
  } else {
    throw Error();
  }
}

function testF<T,K extends keyof T>(obj: T, k: K): WithRequired<T,K> {
  if(isWithRequired(obj, k)) {
    return obj;
  } else {
    throw Error();
  }
}

const a1:A = {};
const a2:A = {f1: 'xyz'};

try {
  const test1 = testF(a1, 'f1');
  console.log('>> test1: ', test1);
} catch {
  console.log('test1 failed');
}

try {
  const test2 = testF(a2, 'f1');
  console.log('>> test2: ', test2);
} catch {
  console.log('test2 failed');
}



Once you are in an if block of a type predicate, the compiler assumes the predicate type.
I modified your original function and added a second one testF that is generic, that is, you can pass it the object and field (as opposed to being specific about type 'A')
